# Возвратить название цвета Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть цвета, задавались для компонентов обычными названиями.

```
pieceColors = new Color[6] {Color.red, Color.blue,
                                Color.yellow, Color.green,
                                Color.cyan, Color.magenta};
```

Теперь, когда я хочу их получить с помощью команды

```
GetComponent<Controller>().getColor (); мне выдаётся 
информация вида RGBA(0.000, 1.000, 0.000, 1.000)
```

Как их получить в виде String?

Пробовал так

```
Color colt = tempPieces[i].GetComponent<Controller>().getColor();

cvet.text = colt.ToString();
```

но всё равно возвращает выдает через RGBA
 Есть ли способ нормально преобразовать названия в английский язык?

Comment: `Color.red` - объект класса, а фактически число `0xFFFF0000`  поэтому без дополнительного кода не представляю как это сделать. А кодом можно просто сделать `switch (color) case Color.red: return "red"...`

Comment: @pavel Ну это вручную. Можно и через if-else Сейчас цветов всего 6, а если их будет 50? Нет какой то возможности это автоматизировать?

Comment: А что это за контроллер и метод `getColor` ? и причем тут `pieceColors `, который нигде тут не указан, кроме как начала вопроса? И разве у `Color` нету свойства `Name` ? ...ведь `Color color = Color.Red;
            string colorName = color.Name; Debug.Log(colorName);` вполне выдаст `Red`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Не работает. 'Color' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'Color' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Вот геттер и сеттер к нему


 `public void setColor(Color newColor) {
  myColor = newColor;
  this.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = myColor;
  
  
 }
 
 
 public Color getColor() {
  return myColor;
 }`

Comment: А если использовать не `UnityEngine.Color`, а `System.Drawing;` будет ошибка?

Comment: Если у вас их будет 50 то задавать им имена вам придется руками в любом случае ибо в Юнити нету 50 предопределеных цветов, а значит вам необходима будет структура с полем для имени, это так к слову. А если говорить про текущую ситуацию то можно посмотреть в сторону рефлексии, хоть это извращение использовать ее в таких обстоятельствах.